# Why is $\ker(id\otimes \cdot b:R/(a)\otimes_R R \to R/(a)\otimes_R R)=R/(d)$?

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit $1_R$, $M$ a $R$-module. Let $a,b\in R\setminus \{0\}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=d$. I want to prove: $$\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(R/(a),R/(b))=R/(d).$$By definition, it is $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(R/(a),R/(b))=H_1(R/(a)\otimes_R P_*)$, where $P_*$ is a projective resolution of $R/(b)$ and $H_1$ is the first (singular) homology.

First consider the projective resolution (with $R$ as a $R$-module): $$0\to R\xrightarrow{\cdot b} R\xrightarrow{p}R/(b)\to 0$$where $p$ is the projection.
The next step is tensoring with $R/(a)$:
$$0\to R/(a)\otimes_R R\xrightarrow{id\otimes \cdot b} R/(a)\otimes_R R\xrightarrow{id\otimes p}R/(a)\otimes_R R/(b)\to 0.$$By definition, it is  $H_1(R/(a)\otimes_R P_*)=\ker(id\otimes \cdot b)$. But I'm stuck to determine the kernel of this map (the kernel must be isomorphic to $R/(d)$).

Let $[x]\otimes r\in R/(a)\otimes_R R$ such that $[x]\otimes br=0$. At this point, I don't know what it means if an element in a tensor product is zero.

Alternatively, instead of $id\otimes \cdot b$ we can consider $$R/(a)\to R/(a),\; [x]\mapsto [xb],$$ because $R/(a)\otimes_R R\cong R/(a)$. Now $[xb]=0$, if $xb\in (a)$. It follows that $xb\in (d)$, because $d=\gcd(a,b)$ (this is strange). But here I don't know how to continue too.
Could you help me to determine the kernel?

Best

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need $b$ to be a non-zero divisor, such that $0 \to R \xrightarrow{\cdot b} R \to R/(b) \to 0$ is indeed a projective resolution.

Then you are on the right track, that you have to compute the kernel of

$$R/(a) \xrightarrow{\cdot b} R/(a).$$

You should check that the kernel is generated by $\frac{a}{d}$ and indeed $\frac{a}{d} \cdot R/(a) \cong R/(d)$.

The hardest part should be that any element of the kernel is a multiple of $\frac{a}{d}$. For that you should precisely define, what it means to be a greatest common divisor in your case (This is not a priori clear in a non-UFD).

I think the weakest definition is the following: Whenever $c|a$ and $c|b$, we have $c|d$. Use this as follows:

Let $x$ be in the kernel, i.e. $xb \in (a)$, hence $a|xb$. It is clear that $a|xa$, hence $a|xd$, so $x\frac{d}{a} \in R$, which means that $x$ is a multiple of $\frac{a}{d}$.